# Rails 3.0.5: Bundler says it'd be using Rack1.2.2 but Passenger casts a GemNotFound Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, bundler

I'm using Passenger with Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.8.7.

It worked fine until some changes I cannot remember.

I hit `bundle install` and it said it'd be using Rack 1.2.2 but Bundler still returns GemNotFound Rack 1.2.2.

As I hit `find / -name "rack"` it shows all the dirs Rack 1.2.2 is installed to and seems that it is installed.

I explicitly demand the Gem Rack 1.2.2 in my Gemfile, also this doesn't help.

Entering the the gemdir by `bundle config path /dir/to/gems` doesn't help as well.

Who can give me right advice or fix this problem?

Thanks,

Yours,

Joern.

Answer (score 1):

your passenger uses another installation of Ruby. set it manualy in `NGINX_FOLDER/conf/nginx.conf`

```
http {
  passenger_ruby /path/to/you/ruby/folder;
  ...
}
```

to know your ruby folder use this command:

```
which ruby
```

**UPD**

For Apache (you can read it in official passenger apache module documentation) http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_unloading_disabling_phusion_passenger_from_apache_without_uninstalling_it. Just set:

```
PassengerRuby /path/to/your/ruby/folder
```

Comment: I'm using Apache2 with passenger

Comment: then change it in appache config :)

Comment: `PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby...`